# Ember Select component rendering before promise is resolved

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, ember-cli, rsvp.js

I have a component which adds some functionality to a `<select>` tag. I want to initialise some javascript after the `<select>` has fully rendered including all `<option>` tags. The data used to populate the `<option>` tags is an array of objects provided from an ajax request.

I'm using ember-data and finding this works when the data is provided from the store, meaning it is an instance of DS.RecordArray which has helpful properties like `isLoaded`. However, when the data is provided from a jQuery ajax call and is just plain JSON, it appears as though the component tries to render everything before the promise returned by jQuery is fulfilled.

I feel the issue is with how I'm handling promises as the issue seems to be related to things initialising before they should (ie promises have resolved properly). I tried wrapping the ajax call in an RSVP.Promise object but not luck, (I'm using Ember-CLI). Below is a simplified version of what I have so far. Any help would be appreciated.

```
// My route
export default Ember.Route.extend({
    setupController: function(controller, model) {
        this._super(controller, model);

        var hash = Ember.RSVP.hash({
                // myOptions: $.getJSON('/api/options')
                myOptions: new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
                    Ember.$.ajax({
                        url: '/api/options',
                        type: 'get',
                        dataType: 'json',
                        success: function(result) {
                            Ember.run(null, resolve, result);
                        },
                        error: function(result) {
                            Ember.run(null, reject, result);
                        }
                    });
                })
            });

        return hash.then(function(result) {
            controller.set('optionsForSelect', result.myOptions);
        });
    }
});

// My component
export default Ember.Select.extend({
    didInsertElement: function() {
        // Is called before ajax request has finished
        this.$().mySelectPlugin({
        });
    }
});

// Handlebars template
{{my-select-plugin content=optionsForSelect optionValuPath="content.id" optionLabelPath="content.name"}}
```

Comment: Returning a promise from `setupController` does not do anything useful. Try returning the promise from `model` (or `beforeModel` or `afterModel`).

Answer (score 2):

To me, this seems like something that should be handled in the controller, not the route. Here's what I did for a similar situation.

```
App.LessonsShowIndexController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({
    author: function() {
        return this.get('model').get('author');
    }.property('author'),
    fullName: function() {
        return this.get('author').get('firstName') + ' ' + this.get('author').get('lastName');
    }.property('author.isFulfilled'),
});
```

Using the isFulfilled property allows the controller to wait for the promise to resolve before using the data. In your case, you could have a property that returns a promise and another that waits for it to be fulfilled.